# Gaps between end-points of lines

Tags: wpf, line

I have an `ObservableCollection` of type `Line` that serves as an `ItemsSource` for `ItemsControl` so that I can draw a graph:

**View:**

```
<ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding LineData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Line> LineData { get; set; }

LineData = new ObservableCollection<Line>();

for (int i = 0; i < stats.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < stats.Length - 1)
    {
        LineData.Add
        (
            new Line()
            {
                X1 = 0.0,
                Y1 = 200 - stats[i],
                X2 = SpanWidth / stats.Length,
                Y2 = 200 - stats[i + 1],
                Stroke = Brushes.SteelBlue
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`SpanWidth` is a property that binds to the width of the `Window` for now (it'll be changed later).  The problem I'm facing is that there are gaps between X1 and X2 points of adjacent lines.

Here's what it looks like when they're viewed in a normal window state:

[image]

Here's what it looks like when the window is stretched out:

[image]

As you can see, the gaps are almost completely gone.  However, to achieve that, I had to stretch the window over the width of two monitors.

I tried snapping to the pixels, but it didn't do much beyond sharpening the edges slightly (by getting rid of anti-aliasing), while the gaps remained.

Is there a way to fix this or will I have to switch to a `Polyline`?  I was hoping to get it done using separate lines due to some of the things I plan on doing later with the individual segments.

**EDIT:**

Looks like Clemens' answer works very well:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest an approach where you would not create UI elements in code. The first step would be to create a derived ItemsControl which uses `Line` objects as item containers:

```
public class LineItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new Line();
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is Line;
    }
}
```

Next, you would use such an ItemsControl in XAML with a Canvas as its `ItemsPanel` and an `ItemsContainerStyle` for the Line items:

```
<local:LineItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}">
    <local:LineItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </local:LineItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <local:LineItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="X1" Value="{Binding X1}"/>
            <Setter Property="Y1" Value="{Binding Y1}"/>
            <Setter Property="X2" Value="{Binding X2}"/>
            <Setter Property="Y2" Value="{Binding Y2}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="SteelBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeStartLineCap" Value="Round"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeEndLineCap" Value="Round"/>
        </Style>
    </local:LineItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</local:LineItemsControl>
```

Finally, you would have a view model item class like this:

```
public class LineItem
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

and add instances of it to a collection property, e.g. like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
...
LineItems = new ObservableCollection<LineItem>();
LineItems.Add(new LineItem { X1 = 20, Y1 = 10, X2 = 100, Y2 = 50 });
LineItems.Add(new LineItem { X1 = 100, Y1 = 50, X2 = 150, Y2 = 150 });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works very well.  Next I'll have to figure out how I can make a standalone `UserControl` out of it so that I can re-use it.

Comment: You might create a Custom Control as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) and put the XAML into `Themes/Generic.xaml`.